# Listen for Change ONLY ONCE on a React Controlled Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, controlled-component

I am attempting to emit a socket event on user input but I want the event to be emitted ONLY ONCE when the value of the input changes in state and another event to be emitted ONCE when the value is cleared.

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");

...

useEffect(()=> {
      if (text) {
        // EMIT EVENT
        console.log("input has value emit event", text);
      } else {
        console.log("input has no value emit event");
      }
}, [text]);

...

const handleChange = e => {
    setText(e.target.value);
}

...

<Input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
```

I am able to accomplish this but my code emits on every keystroke.
My requirement is for both events to emit only once.

- One when there is a value in state
- Another when there is no value in state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the check in `handleChange` instead, so that you can compare the prior value to the new value.

```
const handleChange = e => {
    const newText = e.target.value;
    setText(newText);
    if (newText && !text) {
        console.log("input has value emit event", text);
    } else if (!newText && text) {
        console.log("input has no value emit event");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works sufficiently but is there a way to have the solution in the useEffect block?

Comment: It's possible, but it would be more convoluted. You'd need to store the prior state somewhere for comparison (like state or a ref), or make a separate memoized or state variable for whether the text has anything in it.